# My Backbone Underscore Template ReferenceError?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

:: UPDATE 2 ::

This is my current template,

```
<script type="text/template" id="TimesheetData">  
<form action="#" method="post" id="TimesheetDataList">

<% if(Timesheetrow.jobtitle) { %>

 <div class="TimesheetRowData">
    <input type="hidden" name="data[Timesheetrow][0][id]" value="<%= Timesheetrow.id  %>">
    <input type="type" name="data[Timesheetrow][0][jobtitle]" value="<%= Timesheetrow.jobtitle  %>">
 </div>

<%  }; %>

</form>
<script>
```

And each jobtitle, is in its own form, not one form (which is what I need) but lots of form tags, each one having one of my job titles

Thanks,

---

:: UPDATE ::

This is now what my model is

```
var TimeSheetRowModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
     defaults: {
        Timesheetrow: "",
        Client: "",
        Customer: ""
     }
});
```

---

ok, I have most of this working, but for some reason I can not clear out a RefernceError in my console log. However I do (think) I know way its there but not sure how to sort it out.

So my Backbone code :

```
var TimeSheetRowModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var TimeSheetRowCol = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: TimeSheetRowModel,
    url: '/dashboard/jsondata/' + GetTimesheetID
});

var NewTimeSheetCollection = new TimeSheetRowCol(); //New Instance Of Collecttion

var TimeSheetView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:'#testarea', //HTML loading area for the data

    template: _.template( $('#Timesheet-Data').html() ), //Template to load the JSON data into

    initialize: function(){
      this.listenTo(NewTimeSheetCollection, "add", this.AddMyModel);
      NewTimeSheetCollection.fetch();
    },

    AddMyModel: function(TimeSheetRowModel) {  //apply model data to view template and append to view element   
       //console.log( this.$el.append(this.template(TimeSheetRowModel.toJSON()[0])) );
       $(this.el).html(this.template(TimeSheetRowModel.toJSON()));
    }

});

var NewTimeSheetVew = new TimeSheetView(); //New Instance Of The View    
NewTimeSheetVew.render(); //Render Out The View Instance
```

And my Underscore code :

```
 <script type="text/template" id="Timesheet-Data">    

       <%= console.log(Client) %>  

 </script>
```

Now this does console log all my client data, without any problems and I can also each / print this data into my 'testarea' div.

However in my console log I get,

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: Client is not defined
```

Now from what I have read, this seems to be because I am trying to access as an object (?) and toJSON returns a string - please correct my understand if I have that wrong?

But what I do not understand, is if I am returning the wrong type of output, how can I still access the data? and how should I deal with it, how can I make my toJSON return a object?

Thanks,

Comment: u dont have Client property in TimeSheetRowModel as a result RefError

Comment: Many thanks, I have changed my code, I have updated my question. It does sort my problem, I get no ref. Error but I am still not sure, if I have done it right. - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have that "Client" property in you model?

eg:

```
var TimeSheetRowModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    Client: ""// some value
});
```

Then only you can access the property in view using underscore.

Comment: Sorry, I just got this, I was updating my question while you posted this.

Comment: you have initialized the properties in model with defaults. These can be updated when you pass data into model and you will get them using its object.

Comment: I have a new problem. Underscore is lopping and displaying all html code, and not just the vars. Update my question

Comment: you don't need to use object name to display data on view. just use id instead of Timesheetrow.id in template. if you want to use property in js file you need object.

Comment: You have given id "TimesheetData" in script but you are passing '#Timesheet-Data' in template of TimeSheetView. Is that typing mistake? if yes, you need to give same script id in template. when you pass model to the view and you are rendering the data in view using that model, you don't need mention the object name inside script tag just use model key value i.e "jobtitle" to render data in view.

Comment: Yes but that don't work? - The ID's are the same, I remvoe the '-' form it. If I just ref the id or jobtitle. I get a ref. error jobtitle is not defined

Comment: Its better if you create model for each row so that you don't need to write conditions inside script tags. you can just run loop on json creating models for each row with their views and render them.

Comment: I don't understand why you would ever want to do it that way, plus I have never seen it done that way - got any examples?

Comment: Plus how could you build a model for 'each' row? you would need a loop? I don't know how many rows of data there will be, this is user set data, sorry but I just don't seem to get what you're driving at. Even with the research I have done, I just see only one model for the whoel data set

Comment: would you like to share your email so. that i'll send you demo code..?